# How to count number of edges between red and white nodes in a graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I would like to count how many edges there are that goes between a white and a red node. The red nodes are the ones in the new int[] in the main method.

Provided code for the assignment:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Graph;

public class RedWhite {
    public static int count(Graph G, int[] rednodes) {
        int rw_count = 0;

        // Count how many of the edges in G connect a white node (one that
        // isn't in rednodes) with a red node (one that is in rednodes).

        return rw_count;
    }    
}
```

and

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Graph;

public class TestRW {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph G = new Graph(13);
        G.addEdge(0, 1);
        G.addEdge(3, 2);
        G.addEdge(3, 5);
        G.addEdge(4, 3);
        G.addEdge(4, 2);
        G.addEdge(6, 9);
        G.addEdge(8, 7);
        G.addEdge(8, 9);
        G.addEdge(9, 11);
        G.addEdge(10, 12);
        G.addEdge(11, 12);
        G.addEdge(12, 9);

        System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 3 }));                                        // should print 3
        System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 3, 4, 2 }));                                  // should print 1
        System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 3, 4, 2, 11, 12 }));                          // should print 4
        System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 })); // should print 0
        System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] {  }));                                         // should print 0
    }
}
```

I am having trouble traversing the graph and I don't know how to use rednodes[] to compare to the graph. When running my attempted code below I get errors in the marked and count methods.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Graph;

public class RedWhite {
    private static boolean[] marked;

    public RedWhite(Graph G, int s) {
        marked = new boolean[G.V()];
        dfs(G, s);
    }

    public static int count(Graph G, int[] rednodes) {
        int rw_count = 0;

        for (int w : G.adj(rednodes.length))
        {
            if (marked(w)) {
                rw_count++;
            }
        }

        // Count how many of the edges in G connect a white node (one that
        // isn't in rednodes) with a red node (one that is in rednodes).

        return rw_count;
    }
   
    private void dfs(Graph G, int v) {
        marked[v] = true;
        for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
            if (!marked[w]) {
                dfs(G, w);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean marked(int v) {
        return marked[v];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph G = new Graph(13);
    G.addEdge(0, 1);
    G.addEdge(3, 2);
    G.addEdge(3, 5);
    G.addEdge(4, 3);
    G.addEdge(4, 2);
    G.addEdge(6, 9);
    G.addEdge(8, 7);
    G.addEdge(8, 9);
    G.addEdge(9, 11);
    G.addEdge(10, 12);
    G.addEdge(11, 12);
    G.addEdge(12, 9);

    System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 3 }));                                        // should print 3
    System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 3, 4, 2 }));                                  // should print 1
    System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 3, 4, 2, 11, 12 }));                          // should print 4
    System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 })); // should print 0
    System.out.println(RedWhite.count(G, new int[] {  }));                                         // should print 0
    }
}
```

Comment: *I get errors in the marked and count methods* can you show them here in the question?

Comment: @SomeDude, you must be kidding me. I am not affiliated with arvids4, I was just trying to get the code to run, and decided to post a different question here. I don't know that person. I am sitting in Asia.

Comment: @AlbinM Got it. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Code issues:

You will get an error because `marked` is not initialized because `count` is a static method and it don't need to create a new instance of `RedWhite`.

What you can do is remove `static` from `count` method definition. Also don't declare `marked` as `static`.

And in your main method, do : `RedWhite rw = new RedWhite(G, s) and rw.count(G, new int[]{})`.

- Solution:

Now coming to the solution, I m not sure why you are going for DFS. You have the graph defined, all you need is to look at the adjacency list of each red node and count.

To be more efficient, sort the red nodes and do a binary search for each adjacent node in the sorted rednodes, if it is not found it is a white node. Then increment the count. Do this for all rednodes you will get the final count.

Code is :

```
    private int countEdges(Graph G, int[] rednodes) {
        int count = 0;
        Arrays.sort(rednodes);
        for ( int rednode : rednodes ) {
            for ( int adj : G.adj(rednode) ) {
                if ( Arrays.binarySearch(rednodes, adj) < 0 ) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure, I can agree to this! Why wouldn't DFS work ?

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked great! I still had to use static count though because the assignment is autograded and I can't edit the main method of the file that runs the tests.

Answer (score -1):

To be fair I code in C++, not java, but here's a question: Why does your `marked()` function return the value of a `marked` array? Wouldn't it make more sense to use that array directly?

For the time being I can tell you are using a DFS to traverse the graph correctly. I am not sure, however, why you are traversing the graph at all.

I am sorry, but this is going to be one of these "don't do this, do that instead" answers.

If you are looking for a linear solution (for one execution of the count method), you better just create an array which, **for each node** holds info about whether it is white or red. I'd recommend filling it with zeroes, and then going over the `rednodes` array to change appropriate values to `1`.

Next, you declare a result variable equal to zero, which will count the number of edges which connect to nodes of different colours. You iterate over all the edges, and check if the vertices they connect are of varying colours. If so, increment the result variable.